# Creating function in pandas and applying it

Tags: python, pandas

I have this file. One column is named closing date, the second column is the expected closing date. If the closing date is less than or equal to the expected date then I have to create a column with Value on time. If it is greater than Late in that column. I have to create a function only in Pandas. When I run this code: delay=[]

for ctr in range(approved_crs_ext.shape[0]):
approved_crs_ext=approved_crs['Credit Request: Credit Request Approved'][ctr]-approved_crs['Credit Request: Expected Approval Date'][ctr]
if approved_crs_ext.days>0:
delay.append('Late')
else:
delay.append('On time')
approved_crs_ext['On time Check']=delay
I get an error:
File "", line 4, in 
approved_crs_ext=approved_crs['Credit Request: Credit Request Approved'][ctr]-approved_crs['Credit Request: Expected Approval Date'][ctr]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please add some code/data?

Comment: Please provide a dummy dataset and an expected output, along with what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'closing date': [5,1,10,80], 'expected closing':[3,2,11,75]})
df['new col'] = (df['closing date']<=df['expected closing']).replace(True, 'On time').replace(False, 'Late')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It did updated my records but two records are not correct. How can I fix it. I looked into the data file and got rid of any trailing spaces

Comment: Can you provide the data with incorrect samples?